# Word document not getting inserted using body.insertFileFromBase64 of office.js

Tags: javascript, c#, microsoft-graph-api, word-addins

I am making an Ajax call to the downloaded URL of the word doc located in sharepoint.
File is retrieved successfully as a blob and using the blob, I am getting a base64 string of the file.When I use the same base64 string in  body.insertFileFromBase64(base64data, Word.InsertLocation.start), its showing inserting loader but doesnt insert anything after loader goes off. Am I doing anything wrong? Here is the code I am using.

```
 function InsertDocumentDoc() {


        $.ajax({
            url: '<download-url-link>',
            method: 'GET',
            async:true,
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function (data) {
               


                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(data);
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    var base64data = reader.result;
                    base64data = base64data.substring(base64data.indexOf(",") + 1); 

                    Word.run(function (context) { 
                        var thisDocument = context.document;
                       // // Create a proxy range object for the selection.                       
                        var body = context.document.body;
                     
                       // // Queue a command to replace the body.
                        body.insertFileFromBase64(base64data, Word.InsertLocation.start);

                       // // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
                       // // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
                        return context.sync().then(function () {
                            console.log('Added the content of the file .');
                        });
                    })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                            }
                        });                    
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can refer to [Insert file from Base64 not working as expected](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/819) You can also open an issue on GitHub: [office-js-docs-reference](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-reference)